# Titles alignements with titlesec /etoc

Tags: titlesec, etoc

PLease, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\scshape\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\itshape}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{3cm}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
  {}
  {\addvspace{2ex}\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\ifShowPage % conditional deciding the display or not of the page number
    \llap{\makebox[1.5cm][r]{\mdseries\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
   \fi
    \normalsize\makebox[1cm][r]{\etocnumber\phantom{.}}\hspace{10pt}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-27pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}

\etocsetstyle{section}
  {}
  {\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\llap{\makebox[1.5cm][r]{\mdseries\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
    \normalsize\makebox[1cm][r]{\etocnumber.}\hspace{10pt}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-27pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}

\newif\ifShowPage

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}

\end{document}
```

I'm not able to realize why there is a not wanted indent on  the first chapter title, as in the picture. How is it possible to align this title to the other ones? thanx!
[image]

PS
With pdflatex is all ok, but with xelatex I've this little trouble...

Comment: If I comment `\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}` out, I get the correct behaviour.

Comment: me tpp, but it eliminates this setting in all text and I like t have no indentation inside the text

Answer (score 1):

The following gives correct results for me. I set the `\parindent` locally to 0pt. Note that this isn't really a solution for your problem, more a workaround, as I still don't know what exactly the problem is.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\scshape\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\itshape}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}

\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{3cm}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
  {}
  {\addvspace{2ex}\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\ifShowPage % conditional deciding the display or not of the page number
    \llap{\makebox[1.5cm][r]{\mdseries\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
   \fi
    \normalsize\makebox[1cm][r]{\etocnumber\phantom{.}}\hspace{10pt}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-27pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}

\etocsetstyle{section}
  {}
  {\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
  {\llap{\makebox[1.5cm][r]{\mdseries\etocpage}\hspace{.5cm}}%
    \normalsize\makebox[1cm][r]{\etocnumber.}\hspace{10pt}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm-27pt\relax}{\etocname\par}\hfill\par
  }
  {}

\newif\ifShowPage

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\parindent0pt
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanx. I realize it's a workaound, in fact, as I told, this problem is present in xelatex code, not if I, mutatis mutandis, use pdflatex

Comment: Well, since you don't use the `indentfirst=false` when you use pdfLaTeX and that's the offending line... Until someone posts a better answer, the above seems like a viable (imperfect) solution.

Comment: yes, thanx! even if I'd like to understan the very cause of this behaviour